# Filter CSV lines

Tags: shell, csv, command-line

I have a huge CSV file (4gb) and I need to filter the lines that contains specific strings. For example I need to filter the lines that have the text "McDonalds, BurgerKing or KFC".

I need multiple strings, like an OR.

Something like:

```
 array_of_names = ["McDonalds", "Burger King, "KFC"]
 foreach line in csv
     if line.contains_any_of(array_of_names)
        output << line
     end
 end
```

I think that I can do something with grep but I honestly don't have an idea. I guess I need a shell script.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you just need to filter specific things you can do `grep 'string' big.csv > filtered.csv` but is this a one time thing? And are you going to need to filter multiple strings more than once? Cause that would change the best approach.

Comment: grep "McDonalds, BurgerKing or KFC" filein.csv > fileout.csv

Comment: I need mupltiple strings, like an "OR"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with `grep` like this:

```
 grep "McDonalds\|Burger King\|KFC" your_file.csv
```